# mysql create procedure that will update database

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to create a procedure that will update my database every 30 minutes.
I tried with events but i don't have privileges so they told me -from go daddy- to use procedure. any ideas?

for more help i want every 30 minutes all the players to gain +1 coins.

Comment: you are under linux or win ? which database are you using ?

Comment: windows 7. mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a perl script to access database, look at this link :
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_database_access.htm

then running it periodically as service, look at this link :
http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/Apps/RunPerlScriptAsAService.html

This is just a truck, hope t his would help.

Comment: if this answear was convenient for you thank you for accepting it.